# Lua directly writing string.gmatch to table variable

Tags: lua, string-matching

Is it possible to directly write all output values from gmatch into a table without needing to go through all of them with for?

I got this Export String

```
!Elwynn Forest:Player-3674-0B18B930;false;0;false*!Player-3674-0B18B930:1;Rasudruid;Murky;500;0;1*!currentRound:1*!turnStatus:roll*!currentTurn:1*!
```

and this code to extract the data from the string

```
local function loadGameFromString(importString)
    for exportValue in string.gmatch(importString, '!([^!]+)*') do
        print(exportValue)
        local prefix = string.match(exportValue, '([^:]+):')
        local dataValues = {}
        for data in string.gmatch(exportValue, '[:;]+([^:^;]+)') do
            table.insert(dataValues, data)
        end
        if propertyCards[prefix] then
            print("card")
        elseif string.find(prefix, "Player") then
            playerData[prefix] = {
                playerNumber = dataValues[1],
                name = dataValues[2],
                figure = dataValues[3],
                money = dataValues[4]
            }
        else
            print("gameData")
        end
    end
end
```

right now i would just go through all matches but it takes 4 lines, is there a way to just write it in fewer lines but still keeping the functionality to let me fill the data like that

```
gameData = {
    name = dataValues[1],
    state = dataValues[2]
}
```

Comment: It took me a minute to realize why your code was working at all since you're trying to use the global `string` while it was shadowed by the function's argument. (It's because of the metatable on strings.)

Comment: You're currently not even building a table - you're just printing. What do you mean by "directly writing [...] to table variable?" Your table format also isn't sufficiently specified; you indicate you want `match[1]` and `match[2]` (what's `match`? `exportValue`?), but why are you using `gmatch` at all if you have a fixed number of matches?

Comment: I changed match to dataValues in the code above and instead of only including the prints i also included the part where i write the values into a table what other option besides the way i currently do it do i have ? @Luatic

also with directly writing i meant something like

local a = {sampleTable()}

Comment: @Lars to fill the table use `match` instead of `gmatch` like so `local dataValues = {string.match(exportValue, '[:;]+([^:^;]+)[:;]+([^:^;]+)[:;]+([^:^;]+)[:;]+([^:^;]+)')}`